# CSS only menu close on :target

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover, target

I am using a drop-down menu written in CSS. Been able to get it to my liking but one thing seems to elude me. I want the drop-down menu to close upon mouse click on an item. Fiddling around with `:target` for some time, just cannot make it work.

http://www.jsfiddle.net/DAtLC/

Comment: What is actually supposed to happen when an item is clicked on? The menu closing and *nothing else* does not seem useful.

Comment: Why don't you use JavaScript for that purpose: `$('ul.subs li ul li').on('click', function(){$(this).toggle()})` for example?

Comment: I know the easy way out would be js, but would LOVE to use CSS here too.

Comment: thirtydot, I removed the links in the jsfiddle because they are not important for the question in hand. That part functions well and got no problem there.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to close the menu on clicking an item when the user is then (near) instantly taken to another page. What's the point? From a UX perspective it even seems like a bad idea, though of course that's debatable.

Comment: User stays on same page. Using the menu for a filtering system.