# How do I create a full screen click target to work with CSS-only navigation menu with :target?

Tags: html, css, progressive-enhancement

Related to [StackOverflow question: CSS only menu close on target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009581/css-only-menu-close-on-target), although the question seems to be poorly articulated and therefore didn't receive any answers.

I'm looking to create a navigations menu using progressive enhancement on a **mobile-first** design, so `:hover` isn't an option.  The first step is to implement a JavaScript free navigation drop-down menu using the `:target` pseudo selector.  I'll add a JavaScript solution on top of this later. **The menu will be on a public website that requires support for users who have JS disabled.**

Opening the menu is no problem -- my question comes when it's time to close the menu.  The only way to do this is to remove the id from the URL hash.

For example, the menu appears when you click the following link: `<a href="#nav">Menu</a>` which changes the URL to `www.something.com/#nav`.  In order to hide the menu I need to remove `#nav` from the URL.  The solution is to add another link that changes the hash: `<a href="#top">Close Menu</a>`.

The user will expect that clicking anywhere outside of the menu will close the menu too.  The first solution that comes to mind is to use a little z-index magic to create a full-screen anchor tag just below my menu.

Open to suggestions for other solutions, too.

HTML:

```
<header id="top">
    <a href="#nav" class="toggle-nav">Menu</a>

    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#top">Close Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

SCSS:

```
#nav {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;

    &:not(:target) {
        display: none;
    }

    &:target {
        display: block;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you opposed to using a :hover solution?

Comment: `:hover` isn't available on mobile devices so it would render the navigation menu un-reachable.  I'll add that requirement to the question!

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense then. That is a great question. I've never accounted for JS disabled on mobile.

Comment: Did you think about the "Checkbox hack"? Instead of using :target, my advice would be to use a checkbox or a radio. http://dabblet.com/gist/1507175

Comment: This looks really promising -- I'll report back if I come up with a solution.

Comment: @Roy check it out jsfiddle demo - http://jsfiddle.net/85cxzve0/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by using a `checkbox` and show & hide the navigation by `:checked` selector.

### JSFiddle - [DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/85cxzve0/12/) and [DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/85cxzve0/5/)

**HTML:**

```
<header id="top">
    <label for="toggle-1">Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#top">Close Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ ul#nav {
    display: block;
}
#nav {
    display: none;
}
label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: This works great!  Is there any way to use the checkbox hack method if the element I'm trying to show/hide isn't a direct sibling?

Comment: @Roy It will work for only and all css selectors. Please check the list of css selectors on Mozilla MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors